# Black screen on launch, but normal when press home button and enter the app again

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title, my app will occasionally show a black screen at launch, but I don't know why.

When I press the home button, then entered it again, I saw it was running well. It seems the window could not be made visible randomly. But I don't know when or why does it happen.

Answer (score 2):

You likely don't have a launch image set. When apps are loading their resources they display a launch image, you likely don't have one, which is why you get a black screen.

The reason it doesn't always appear is because if the app is in the background, but still alive, it keeps its resources available for a quick start from the background. It then does not need to display the launch image.

[See the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry for not describing the question more clearly. I know exactly what you mean, but the problem I've met is that...the black screen appears at exact launch(I mean, the app wasn't going to background before, for example, when I run it from click "build and run" button, it will launch at a simulator or device).And the black screen won't disappear and jump to app rootViewController unless I press the home button to home screen and enter the app again. SO,I think maybe there are some problem with navigationController or rootViewController...~^_^

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that there is something wrong with the NavigationController/ViewController stack for Your application. I've had similar situations with exact same problem.

What You can do:

- It is pretty hard to suggest something - usually needs tinkering around with the stack structure (maybe try to simplify the stack (remove unnecessary navigationControllers / any tabbarControllers?
- Create a separate project, with the same navigationController/ViewController structure, to replicate the problem,  upload somewhere, give access to us and we can take a look. But probably - when You will start tinkering around - You will fix the issue Yourself.

Comment: Thanks,I think my problem is just like what you mean,I will keep checking my codes,especially the appDelegate.m and navigationControllers, I've met the same problem in my two different apps. any way,thank you~